# Is a lookup table what I need for this issue?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing this in MySQL and PHP. I have three tables which are:

- A Users table - 
  user_id, username
- A Characters table - 
  id_chars, char_1, char_2... char_8
- A Professions table - 
  id_profession, profession, name... (columns continue)

Right now, I only have PK's no FK's at all. Just the main structure with test data in it.

What I'm trying to do is make one User to many Professions and one User to many Characters.

In this way, one could select a User, then select from a list of Characters assigned to said User, then flag one or many items in the Professions list. Making so that for each User/Character pairing the flagged items in the Professions list are uniquely being tracked.

Comment: so what is the question?

Comment: Yes. That's what you need.

Comment: I'm looking for how to implement this? How should the Table Relations look when I'm done. Also @tadman asked to see my schema, what's the best way to do this on stackoverflow?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes.

The long answer involves your schema which you haven't specified.

Comment: I've updated my original question? What I'm having trouble with is understanding how the lookup table functions and what it is supposed to look like. Once I have it in place, what would my query look like?

Comment: Remember your [Zero, One or Many Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) when structuring your tables. I don't know what `char_1` and so forth is, but that seems highly broken. Those should be individual records associated with the user in question.

Comment: If you're using a robust [PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) you'll have several tools available to properly structure your data and make implementing and *testing* your application a fairly straight-forward process.

Comment: Each user has a max of 8 characters(char_# for short) so, i guess the question would be should the characters all be listed in the user table or should the char's have there own table? I've gone back and forth on this one and couldn't come up with a conclusion... I guess it only makes my user table 8 column's longer...

Comment: I just read your PHP framework post... I just built from the ground up, a light CMS for this project, and I'm just now working on the guts of this project.

Comment: Building from the ground up is usually a very bad idea. These frameworks give you a ton of tools that are very powerful and would take a long time to write yourself. They also have a lot of community-provided add-ons that could save you a ton of time implementing something that's already a solved problem. When I hear "built from ground up", I hear "application that's going to by very difficult to maintain".

Comment: Always create separate records for things like characters unless you have a very good reason to avoid this. `CREATE TABLE characters (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, user_id INT, name VARCHAR(255))` as an example.

Comment: I don't understand why you would want two id's? id is your PK, what would user_id be for? Why wouldn't you just want, user_id PK, username?

Comment: How else can you associate these characters with a given user? Remember a primary key is unique, so unless you want a one-to-one association, you'll need the secondary ident. This is how a one-to-many relationship is defined.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, a lookup table is what you need. Lookup tables are useful in situations where a unique key corresponds to a value which itself could be a list of items. Your situation lends itself to a lookup based on what you've told us